# When I try to login in wordpress it is showing "USER Doesn't Exists"

Tags: users, login

The main Issues is that I am entering the email address & password that I used in creating my WordPress site in digital but It shows that the email address & username doesn’t exist even I checked in my PhpMyAdmin “WordPress” “wp-user” and I am using the right email, username and password but still shows that user doesn’t exist. However, I tried changing password by using “lost password” section but in that whenever enter my username or email to get a password reset link it shows user doesn’t exist, so what should I do to fix, please help…

I appreciate any answer, please help, if need any other pieces of information with this issue I can give.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Reset your password directly from phpmyadmin. To do this, log in to it, find the user table (by default, wp_users), and find the entry with your username. On the left, select the "Edit" link to open the edit panel. Find the user_pass field. Next to it, select MD5 in the checkbox, and enter a new password in the next field. After entering, click save and try logging in to Wordpress with a new password.

Comment: I did it so many time but It doesn't work, brother, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to check your DB, if there is any ghost user with admin rights it means you are hacked and you should clean your WP installation.

If it's clean just check the admin username and use it to log in.

here is where and how you will find users in DB:

Once logged in, find your database in the left column and click it once.
That will reveal a list of tables. We only care about two tables: **wp_usermeta** and **wp_users**

Let’s start with **wp_users**. Click that table link and you’ll see something like this:

[image]

What’s important here are the numbers in the User ID column. Note how one is 2 and the other is 101011. These are good users in our installation.

We are going to do a database query to identify the invisible users. Click the SQL tab.
[image]

Next, copy/paste the text below into the box and click the “Go” button bottom right.

```
select * from wp_usermeta where meta_value LIKE '%administrator%';
```

This will do a quick search for all currently set administrator users.

[image]

After our search notice the extra users

Now kill the other users. Click on the big red **X** next to each bad users.

Comment: I checked and didn't find anything like this, but still, I can't log in in Wp-Login any other method, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you provide your website URL?

Comment: https://newwayelegant.com is my site url

Comment: You should access your Database and follow my post

Comment: I think something is wrong with the database because I tried running the wp-CLI command "wp user create user_name email_id --role=administrator" and It shows "Database Error "database_name.wp_user" doesn't exist for the query,